# How to pass an arg to the function inside lodash's once function?

Tags: javascript, lodash

So I am calling a function that calls lodash's once function:

```
  if (isPageTwo) {
    sendSegmentData(sendEnhancedTrackEvent);
  }
```

And I have the functions defined here:

```
const pageTwoSegmentEvent = (sendEnhancedTrackEvent) => {
  const enhanceableData = {
    name: 'Page loaded',
    properties: {
      ...defaultProps,
      cid: getCid(),
      epid: getEpid(),
      name: 'ReviewExperienceModernDoubleStep'
    }
  };
  sendEnhancedTrackEvent(enhanceableData);
}
const sendSegmentData = (sendEnhancedTrackEvent) => {
  once(() => {
    pageTwoSegmentEvent(sendEnhancedTrackEvent);
  });
}
```

I am trying to pass the sendEnhancedTrackEvent callback function to the pageTwoSegmentEvent function but I guess the way I'm trying to pass it through the once function pageTwoSegmentEvent never gets called.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The `_.once()` method takes a function (func), and returns a function that invokes the wrapped function (func) a single time. According to the docs:

> The func is invoked with the this binding and **arguments** of the created
>   function.

Which means that whatever arguments you pass to the new function, will be passed to the wrapped `func`.

In your case:

1. `sendSegmentData` has the `sendEnhancedTrackEvent` param
2. When `sendSegmentData` is invoked, it calls `once(() => { pageTwoSegmentEvent(sendEnhancedTrackEvent); });`, which creates a new function. The new function is not returned or called.

To create `sendSegmentData`, call `once` on `pageTwoSegmentEvent` directly. This will return a new function, that will pass whatever arguments in gets to `pageTwoSegmentEvent`.

**Example:**

```js
const { once } = _

const pageTwoSegmentEvent = (sendEnhancedTrackEvent) => console.log(sendEnhancedTrackEvent)

const sendSegmentData = once(pageTwoSegmentEvent)

sendSegmentData('1')

sendSegmentData('2')

sendSegmentData('3')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

_.once returns the function that you need to invoke. No matter how many times you call this function it will only be invoked once.

Assuming `once` is an alias to `_.once`, try changing it to this:

```
const sendSegmentData = once((sendEnhancedTrackEvent) => {
    pageTwoSegmentEvent(sendEnhancedTrackEvent);
});

...

// somewhere else call it
sendSegmentData(theSegmentedData);
```